# How to use different theme for same database by using multi site?

Tags: 8, theming, nodes

I am working on the drupal8 multi site  . I have setup with different database its working fine. But I want to use with same database and different theme for both the sites  which I have created by multi site

I have created the themes folder inside the sites/site1/art .
but its using the same theme for both multi site

```
http://localhost/site1
http://localhost/site2
```

How can i use the different theme for diffenent sites?

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/switch_page_theme or https://www.drupal.org/project/domain_theme_switch or https://www.drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher or etc.

Comment: yes its using the same theme ,when I create theme in the site1 folder its also using  in localhost/site2

Comment: how can I use http://localhost/site1 i by using domin theme  switch?

Comment: You have to figure out yourself.

Comment: WIth different databases you should just be able to change the theme in the appearances settings.  The theme files should be located under the main /theme directory in either the custom or contrib directories.

Comment: @CGMonroe - They want to use only one database.